# generatedDensities -does it work for PNG drawables or just SVG

Tags: android, svg, android-gradle-plugin

In gradle android plugin 1.4 there is a property called [generatedDensities](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/1.4/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:generatedDensities)

My question is in regards to what it does exactly. I realize if i use it like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId “com.myproject.box"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName “6.0"
        generatedDensities = ['mdpi', 'hdpi']
    }
```

That only mdpi and hdpi drawable folders will be generated in the final build. But i want to know will it for PNGs. Lets say i have ONLY PNG drawables and i run genereatedDensities, does it keep the PNG files or does it only work on SVG files ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/1.4/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:generatedDensities) from ProductFlavor, the plugin will generate PNG files. It looks like it works with vector drawables (SVG) to create PNGs for each density, so this won't have any effect on any PNGs you create.

Comment: So what im asking is if i have a ONLY PNG files and my end goal is to generated only mdpi and hdpi drawable folders, will generatedDensities = ['mdpi', 'hdpi'] do this and preserve all my PNGs ?

Comment: No, it looks like the line only works with SVG, so it won't do anything with your PNGs.

Comment: could you explain how you know it only keeps SVG files, not doubting you just how did you come to know ?

Comment: @j2emanue The documentation says it does, I didn't test it myself so I may be wrong but just check it out.